# How can I write the pipe command Linux in Windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I write the `|` (Linux) command in a Windows cmd (batch file)?

I don't know how to write this little Linux script in Windows:

```
find -r * |grep *.fd | open
```

In Windows:

```
dir /S ???  open
```

Comment: The "| command" is not a command, per se. You might be interested to read more about [pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))

Comment: Also, btw, `find . -name '*.fd' | open` is cleaner for the linux version.

Comment: i know what is the pipe, was just too late for a good question, but now I discovered the presence of the powershell, thanks Joey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what `open` does. If it simply starts an associated application with the respective file, then the following should do it:

```
for /r %f in (*.fd) do (start "" "%f")
```

In PowerShell you can do the same with:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.fd | Invoke-Item
```

or shorter:

```
gci -rec -fi *.fd | ii
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular command shell in windows is lacking in power and features. However, Windows Power Shell has the ability to run a lot of ninja commands similar to *nix shells.

You can get more information about power shell on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Here is an example I googled from Powershell help itself:

> -------------------------- EXAMPLE 4 --------------------------
>
> C:\PS>get-childitem
>   c:\windows\system32* -include *.txt
>   -recurse | select-string -pattern "Microsoft" -casesensitive
>
> This command examines all files in the
>   subdirectories of C:\Windows\System32
>   with the .txt file extension, for the
>   string "Microsoft". The CaseSensitive
>   parameter indicates that the 'M' in
>   'Microsoft' must be capitalized and
>   the rest of the characters must be
>   lowercase for a match to occur.